# Ubuntu 14.10 transparent window title bar

Tags: unity, transparency, titlebar

Is there a way to make the window title bars transparent in 14.10? 
The transparent panel and launcher looks wonderful, but without the transparency of the title bars, the whole surface looks inconsistent.

Answer (score 3):

Install and then open dconf, then goto org > compiz > gwd, edit ''metacity-theme-active-opacity'' and/or ''metacity-theme-inactive-opacity'' change value 1.0 to 0.9...
done, works for me in ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: This method is not working for me, but I saw that this method is used by many users. Did there exists any other method?

Comment: You can also try ''gconf'' app, gwd and edit values.

Comment: Already tried, but without success. I think that there is something else which overrides these settings, but I can't figure out what it is. Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: Maby it is something that gnome allows...I use cairo dock not gnome but i have to install it to make it work, or maby it depend on compiz with compiz settings turn on opacity?

Comment: Working, I put 0,50

Answer (score 0):

Unity Tweak Tools will handle that. It also gives access to other customization features like hotcorners , window snapping, and what the third mouse button does. It's available in the Software Center.

Comment: As far as i know, unity tweak tool can't change the transparency of the title bars, since 12.10 or something. It can only deal with the panel...